# Does the data that is shown only after scrolling (paging) is part of the dom when page is loaded?

Tags: java, selenium, dom, automation

I'm trying to understand the following code:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id("123"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",elem);
```

I read that this code is useful in places like Facebook where there is a paging process.

**But** I'm thinking that if the element will be seen only after paging, doesn't it mean that the first line `WebElement Elem = driver.findElement(By.id("123"));` will throw an exception, since the element isn't part of the **Dom** yet (Until the paging will arrive at this item)?

Comment: This may scroll to an item at the bottom of the page which is already in the DOM and which internally triggers more content to be loaded when it is actually visible.

Comment: @luk2302, so upon launching, the DOM stores post that the user had posted years ago?

Comment: This is not answerable, it **ENTIRELY** depends on the website you are browsing and what that site is doing.

Answer (score 2):

Line by line explantion:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id("123"));
```

the driver is a web driver reference, using that you can call `findElement` method and pass the locator like `id` with the help of By which is `an abstract` class in selenium.

Selenium talk and communicate with HTMLDOM, so if you see `123` as an `id` in **HTMLDOM** then there will not be any error/exception.

But if the `123` id web element is not present or not rendered properly then you would see an exception related to **WebElement**.

```
JavascriptExecutor
```

is basically an interface in `Selenium-Java` bindings.

and this line

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elem);
```

this line is basically taking two args. `second arg` is a web element (`elem`) in your case. and `arguments[0]` represent the specified web element and we are invoking `JS - scrollIntoView(true);` method on top of that.

Comment: @cruiseoandey, Thanks. But in what it depends if an element with id of **123** will be found or not?

Comment: if `driver.findElement(By.id("123"));` this does not found on the DOM, you will likely get an exception. But make sure you are checking this in HTMLDOM, not just on the UI.

Comment: the HTMLDOM is what i'm seeing when using *inspect*?

Comment: yes, that's correct! 
**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `id` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium imitates a real user actions via the UI.
So, as a user you can not click etc. element that is not appearing on the visible screen view. This is why Selenium driver will throw you an exception in case you try to access such element.
However this element can exist on the DOM.
It can be completely rendered or not, depends on the specific technology how that specific web page is implemented, but the web element will exist.
JavaScript can access invisible and still not fully rendered elements. So, with JS you can perform several actions Selenium driver will not allow you to do.
But this will not imitate real human user actions via the UI.

Comment: Can you please explain your last sentence: **But this will not imitate real human user actions via the UI.** Why it won't imitate real human user action?

Comment: In case the element is not on the visible screen section, as a user you first have to scroll the page to reach it. How, as a user, you can interact with such element directly, without scrolling? You can't!

Comment: So the row js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elem);  will imitate user scrolling?

Comment: I'm not completely sure this can be defined as a real user page scrolling, but yes, it will scroll the page. I think scrolling with `Actions` can be defined a user scrolling imitation. I don't know what are (if there) differences between these 2 ways.

Comment: thank you. I was sure scrolling isn't available via *Action* object and therefore we use the **JavascriptExecutor** object

Comment: There is `action.moveToElement(webElement).build().perform();`

Comment: In case my answer resolved your issue please accept it

Comment: Both answers are good. I need to decide :)